Add color with extrude region
I am working on adding graphic logo over cylinder using blender script and want to add colors. For cylinder color works fine using materials but for logo I am not getting idea how to add color. I am using Plane and extrude for creating graphic logo. Below is my code:
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="FACE")
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_shrink_fatten(
        MESH_OT_extrude_region={
            "use_normal_flip": False,
            "use_dissolve_ortho_edges": False,
            "mirror": False,
        },
        TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={
            "value": item_graphic_extrude,
            "use_even_offset": False,
            "mirror": False,
            "use_proportional_edit": False,
            "proportional_edit_falloff": "SMOOTH",
            "proportional_size": 1,
            "use_proportional_connected": False,
            "use_proportional_projected": False,
            "snap": False,
            "release_confirm": False,
            "use_accurate": False,
        },
        #Material=mat,
    )

Can I add Material with extrude region?
